# Haskellのラムダ式のパターンマッチに関する質問です。

Tags: haskell

Haskellを勉強して1週間ほどなので、馬鹿らしい質問かもしれませんがあらかじめ御了承ください。

Haskellの勉強中にふとラムダ式でパターンは使えるのかと思い、下のような関数を作りました

```
pow :: Num a => a -> Integer -> a
pow x = do
    \0  -> 1
    \1  -> x
    \2  -> x * x
    \n  -> 
        if even n   then pow (pow x 2) (n `div` 2)
        else             x * pow (pow x 2) ((n - 1) `div` 2)
```

しかし、これを実行するとコンパイルは通るのですが、無限ループになってしまっているようなのです。
なぜ、無限ループの陥ってしまうのかを教えていただきたいです。

開発環境はOS:Windows 10、コンパイラ：ghc 8.6.3です。

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Haskellの勉強中にふとラムダ式でパターンは使えるのかと思い、

残念ながら少なくとも標準のHaskellでは使えません。
`LambdaCase`というGHCによる言語拡張を有効にする必要があります。

言語拡張を有効にする場合、下記のような特殊なコメントを、ファイルの先頭に書いてください。

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE LambdaCase #-}
```

GHCi上で試したい場合、下記のように入力してください。

```hs
:set -XLambdaCase
```

しかしいずれにしても、ラムダ式の中でパターンマッチをする構文は、tokumeimanxxさんに挙げていただいたようなものではありません。

にもかかわらずなぜコンパイルが通ったのかというと、それは`do`を使ったからです。
`do`は通常、Monad型クラスのインスタンスである型の値（「アクション」とも言います）を行ごとに列挙するのに使用するのですが、tokumeimanxxさんが書いたように、それ以外の式を行ごとに列挙するのにも使えます。
なので、tokumeimanxxさんの例で言う`\0  -> 1`、`\1  -> x`といった行は、**それぞれ別々のラムダ式として解釈**されてしまっています。
`do`記法にアクションでない、普通の式を列挙した場合、結果を`let`で代入しなければ、それらの**式は無視**されてしまいます。
結果、最後の行に当たる

```
    \n  -> 
        if even n   then pow (pow x 2) (n `div` 2)
        else             x * pow (pow x 2) ((n - 1) `div` 2)
```

のみが有効な式として解釈されたため、`if`式の`then`節も`else`節もどちらでも再帰している上記の式によって、無限ループとなってしまった、ということです。

この、「`do`に列挙した式の結果をどこにも代入してない」という間違いは、GHCの警告を有効にすることで、検出できます。

例えば、tokumeimanxxさんのコードを`pow.hs`という名前で保存した上で、`GHCi`上で下記のように入力すれば、その警告を見ることができるでしょう。

`warning: [-Wunused-do-bind]`と書かれている警告が、当該の警告です。

```
> :set -Wall
> :l pow.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( pow.hs, interpreted )

pow.hs:3:5: warning: [-Wunused-do-bind]
    A do-notation statement discarded a result of type ‘Integer’
    Suppress this warning by saying ‘_ <- \ 0 -> 1’
  |
3 |     \0  -> 1
  |     ^^^^^^^^

... 省略 ...
Ok, one module loaded.
```